# IOS Auto Generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular, sidekick

I use NativeScript for develop on windows planform.

When I try set live connect with my Iphone, I had message about certificate.

In Sidekick exist special function called "IOS Auto Generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate". [Official guide](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-with-nativescript-sidekick)

> Not to mention, if you don't have a valid iOS provisioning profile and certificate pair, Sidekick can automatically generate them for you with a free Apple account:

[image]

But when I try to use it I get error.

if i understand correctly, I no need paid apple developer account. This is true?

Because I create Free Apple account. And I want just testing my app on real device.

Comment: You don't need a paid account to test on a single device.  You do need to enrol your Apple ID in the free developer program level.  Have you done that?

Comment: @Paulw11, I register on "https://developer.apple.com/account/", do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

What's your package name? Your package name must be really unique among anything ever created so far, for example test, test123, demo etc., would have been taken already. Try adding random numbers at end of your package name, mostly that helps.

Comment: it should be unique for all type of program (free/paid).